# Repeating command in gwt

Tags: gwt, flextable

I use flex table to show the data fetched from db. When table contains a large amount of columns it takes much time to render the flextable(I've tested it on table with 80 columns and 38 rows) and while it is not completely rendered I can not do anything with a page. So i use `Schedule.get().scheduleIncremental(ReapitingCommand command)` as follows:

```
final int  WORK_CHUNK = 2;    
Scheduler.get().scheduleIncremental(new RepeatingCommand() {
            int rowCounter = 0;

            @Override
            public boolean execute() {
            for (int i = rowCounter; i < rowCount; i++, rowCounter++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < columnCount; j++) {
                table.setText(i, j, data.get(i)[j]);
                }
                if (rowCounter % WORK_CHUNK == 0)
                return true;
            }
            return false;
            }
        });
```

But if i have 9 rows and 3 columns in `data` object it only render 2 rows.
How I can improve its performance, because as I said earlier if have 38 rows and 80 columns it takes too much time to render all the data without `scheduleIncremental`. Even browser popups the window that script may have stoped responing.

Comment: Use a CellTable, thank yourself later.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't use a [CellTable](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCellTable.html) instead of a FlexTable to render your data?
CellTable is supposed to be much more efficient in rendering large amounts of data compared to FlexTable.

Comment: because I only need to output data. I need not that code overhead that CellTable provides

Comment: @maks you have it completely backwards. FlexTable has high overhead. CellTable on the other hand will render very large number of rows very quickly. It also provides paging with ease.

Comment: As you can see from the code in my question I use data object which contains the data from database. To use the CellTable  I have to create a  TextCell<T> to output data, but its getValue method has a parameter of object which has to contain concrete field to output its value. However I don't have such concrete fields. I save the data in object that has list of arrays, so I need some iteration logic to output them

Answer (score 2):

For above code I would have done it this way. Get rid of the first for loop because execute() is recursive.

```
Scheduler.get().scheduleIncremental(new RepeatingCommand() {
    int rowCounter = 0;
    int rowCount = 10;

@Override
public boolean execute() {

// do some work
    for (int j = 0; j < columnCount; j++) {
    table.setText(i, j, data.get(i)[j]);
}

rowCounter++;

if (rowCounter >= rowCount)
    return false;

return true;
   }
});
```